# Common RecyclerView and use it everywhere

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to develop an app with RecyclerView. In my app, many more listing and all the moments I want call same data. But the problem is, every time I have to write code for binding adapter in various Activity, Fragment, server side connecting response and some other.So I am thinking to create a single Android RecyclerView and use it everywhere in the app where it is required.

So how it is possible. I am using Json with retrofit and MySQL for more operation to perform on adapter and RecyclerView.Community friends, please help me.

friend i have wait for last five days for your answer please help it...

Comment: Create a separate layout file, put your recyclerview inside it and then wherever you want to reuse it, simply <include> it in your activity/fragment XML?

Comment: bro its not just for layout its all kind of java file data and binding

Comment: You can use your recycler adapter anywhere, just feed it with the new activity/fragment`s data(arraylist or whatever you are using). I cant really give accurate answer due to lack of knowledge on your code part.

Comment: If you need to reuse the same RecyclerView with the same data type, you need to make a custom view.